# Does `Sequence<T>.all` loop remaining elements in case it runs into an element which doesn't match the predicate?

Tags: kotlin

`Sequence<T>.all` returns true when all elements match the given predicate.

```
inline fun <T> Sequence<T>.all(
    predicate: (T) -> Boolean
): Boolean
```

Let's say. It encounters an element which doesn't match the predicate before reaching to the last element. I think it doesn't need to loop to the end and can return false from there. Does it loop through all elements even in case?

Comment: What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I want to know if it returns false in the middle or if it goes through all elements even though an element in the middle doesn't match the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it loop through all elements even in case?

No. You can refer to source code.

```
public inline fun <T> Sequence<T>.all(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    for (element in this) if (!predicate(element)) return false
    return true
}
```

Whenever predicate is resolved to false, false is returned from `.all` immediately.